# Why I cant make an intent in my "public class adapter extends PagerAdapter" to MainActivity2s

Tags: java, android-studio, android-viewpager

**this is a click listener for pages of view pager**

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2s.class);**
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast.makeText(context,"intent Tow ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        Toast.makeText(context,"intent Three ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                }
            }
        });
```

**=>**there i get this error ('com.example.app.MainActivity' is not an enclosing class)**

Answer (score 0):

I think your adapter is not an inner class of `MainActivity` , thus you cannot call `MainActivity.this`. I'm guessing what you are trying to do and what you should do rather is to populate fragments **not** activities when `ViewPager` is scrolled.

You may take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) if that is the case.

Comment: I want to make a click listener for each fragment with onClickListener.And thank you